# Did I understand the concept of DFA's (Deterministic Finite Automatons) right?

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory, finite-automata, dfa, deterministic

I very new to DFA's and I need some help to understand them.

Are my DFA's (deterministic finite automaton) correct?

[image: Here are my DFA's]

The #a(w) & #b(w) denote the number of a and b, respectively, in the word w.

I feel like they are still not quite right..

I'm really grateful for any help! Thank you so much!

Comment: They are all right as far as I can tell, but L2 can be simpler if you merge q1 and q2.

Comment: I agree with Paul. BTW, if you have future questions about DFAs, cs.stackexchange.com would be a better fit.